# unable to find target file after running pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps and am trying to use Google Maps for iOS and I followed the above instructions from https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/693 to do so I get an error from the pod install:

Unable to find a target named `AirMapsExplorer`

here is the podfile that I have

```
# You Podfile should look similar to this file. React Native currently does not support use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

# Change 'AirMapsExplorer' to match the target in your Xcode project.
target 'AirMapsExplorer' do

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', path: '../../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'BatchedBridge'
  ]

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # <~~ remove this line if you do not want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../../'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../../'  # <~~ if you need GoogleMaps support on iOS

end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "react-native-google-maps"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I rebooted my device (2 times now) removed the pod folder and podfile, followed the instructions again and get the same error. I even tried doing clean build and clean folder still to no avail.

anyone have this error or run into a way to fix if you run into this. I don't use xcode regularly as I am building with React Native and try not to do much with xcode unless I absolutely have to for iOS.

If there are other things you want me to show I will to help debug this issue. Thank you

Comment: Had you used cocoapods before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put in your target the name of the `xcodeproj` created by XCode when you start this project, you also need to check that your `.podFile` is in your `xcodeproj` file directory , also I think you are missing this line

```
workspace 'AirMapsExplorer'
```

This will create a workspace with your pods integrated

**your pod file modified**

```
# You Podfile should look similar to this file. React Native currently does not support use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

workspace 'AirMapsExplorer'

# Change 'AirMapsExplorer' to match the target in your Xcode project.
target 'AirMapsExplorer' do

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', path: '../../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'BatchedBridge'
  ]

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # <~~ remove this line if you do not want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../../'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../../'  # <~~ if you need GoogleMaps support on iOS

end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "react-native-google-maps"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ReinierMelian...No I have not used cocoa pods before. This is actually the first time using them. Apparently, there need to be some updated installation steps to get this to work that they forgot but your above example helped. I did have to change the target to 'MY PROJECT NAME' but that actually was a start to getting this solution solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @T.Evans your welcome, I am Glad to help you, happy coding and best regards